# Jquery slideToggle finish

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

i try change arrow to UP when div is open and to DOWN when DIV is close

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".component_wrapper").hide();
 $(".component_expand").show().click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle();
    $(this).css("background-image","url(images/106.png)");
});
```

});

Comment: did you check my answer too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle(function(){
    //this code runs when slide toggle is done.. 
    //Here you will have to see if the div is visible or not and apply the appropriate code
});
```

Hard to know exactly without your HTML but something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".component_wrapper").hide();
    $(".component_expand").show().click(function () {
      $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle(function(){
        if($(this).is(':visible'))
         $('.component_expand').html('up arrow'); 
        else
         $('.component_expand').html('down arrow');   
      });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwbhm/

**Update 2**

This example is better and will worth with multiple `.component_expands`

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwbhm/1/

Comment: you can make example, pls

Comment: @allpnay Check my update to see if that helps.. If not can you include your html?

Comment: @allpnay if you have multiple `.component_expand` elements then this will work better.  http://jsfiddle.net/Hwbhm/1/